# New fetched row overwriting the previous row while writing to a table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
        <head>  
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
               <script>
                       function submit() {
                                            document.getElementById("myform").submit();
                                          }
                       window.onload = function() {
                                                   document.getElementById("textbox").focus();
                                                 };
                </script>
        </head>
     <body>
      <form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <h1> AWB_NO</h1>
      <input type=text id="textbox" name="excel" onchange="submit()">
      </br>
      </form>
        <?php
             error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
         $vars = $_COOKIE['var1'];
         if(!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
             $_SESSION['items'] = array();

            }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['arr2'])) {
            $_SESSION['arr2'] = array();
            }
         $var='';
        if(isset($_POST['excel']))
        {
         $host="localhost";
         $user="root";
         $password="";
         $db="greenmobiles";
         $table="manifest";
         $var=$_POST['excel'];  
         $con=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password") or die("Cannot Connect");
         mysqli_select_db($con,"$db") or die("Cannot select DB!");    
             if (in_array($var,$_SESSION['items']))
             {
               echo"The new value has been scanned!</br>";
               echo "<hr>";
               echo "The tracking id's of the currently scanned items are given below<br><hr>";
               foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $x => $value)
               {
                echo "$value";
                echo "<br>";
               }
                echo "<script>alert('oops! This item has already been scanned!')</script>";
             }
             else
             {
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE awb_no = '$var'";
               $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  
                   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                   {
                     echo "tracking id present in the manifest</br>";
                   } 
                   else 
                   {
                     echo "<script>alert('Tracking id is not present in the manifest!')</script>";
                   }
             $sqli = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var') AND (document_no='$vars')";
             $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);  
             if (mysqli_num_rows($result1)) 
               {
                 echo "The tracking id matches with the document no.";
               }
             else
               {
                 echo "<script>alert('Tracking id does not belong to the document number entered.')</script>";
                 exit(0);
               } 
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
                    $_SESSION['data'][] = $row['awb_no'];
                    $_SESSION['items'] = $_SESSION['data'];
              } 
             mysqli_free_result($result);
             echo"The new value has been scanned!</br>";
             echo "<hr>";
             echo "The tracking id's of the currently scanned items are given below<br><hr>";
             echo '<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 panel">'."<table class='table'>
                   <tr>
                   <th>Document No</th>
                   <th>AWB NO</th>
                   <th>Order Id</th>
                   <th>Forms</th>
                   <th>Extras</th>
                   </tr>";
                   echo "<tr>";
                   $sqlq= "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE awb_no = '$var'";
                   $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlq);
                   if ($result2)
                {
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result2))
                   {
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                    }
                      echo "</table></div>";

                 }
            }

            }

         else
              {
                session_destroy();
              }
?>
</body>
    </html>
```

Hello, i am new to php and html. I am giving an input to a text box whose value is '$var' and retrieving data one row at a time and trying to print it in a html table via php. But each time i enter a value the previous row gets overwritten by the new row and i am not able to keep the previous rows and append the new ones to my table. Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: You are invoking `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);` twice.  Your `if` should just be `if ($result)...`.

Comment: @andy i changed that. But a new row isnt being created, it's still overwriting the previous row

Comment: If you've modified your code, please go back and edit the question to show us the new code.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the previous row gets overwritten by the new row"?  Are you talking about database rows or HTML table rows?  It's not possible for an `echo` statement to overwrite previous output.

Comment: Basically i enter a value into the text box. That particular row is fetched from the database and printed as a html row in the same page. Now when i enter another value the row is fetched from the database and that row writes over the first value row. So now instead of having two rows,i still have one as the new row writes over the first html table. Would u like me to post the whole code?

Comment: I have posted it all.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: And youre not "overwriting" previous rows. You're doing full-blown form submissions, and each search you do is a **NEW** page, which results only from the previous search. If you want to "append" search results, you'd have to remember all previous searches, or use ajax to fetch new rows and insert them into the page.